# Two wordpress with two sitemaps under same domain name

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have two wordpress installations under one domain name, as this:

```
www.exampleWP1.com
www.exampleWP1.com/exampleWP2/
```

I have both of them created in Search Console as independant properties, in Tag Manager each with it's own tag and container, etc.

Just recently I noticed when I add sitemaps in the `ExampleWP2` Search Console, it automatically adds the same sitemaps it in the `ExampleWP1` Search Console aswell. I don't understand how or why, are the properties linked somehow??

I tested deleting all sitemaps, adding them again, and still happens.

I think I could try deleting all sitemaps from Search Console on both properties and keep them in each site's robots.txt, is that a viable option?

Also, both accounts are linked by the same company email... is it possible for that to be the cause?

Please someone advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does only see one website `ExampleWP1.com` with a subdirectory `ExampleWP1.com/ExampleWP2`

So it's quite fair it believes `ExampleWP1.com` is the root of this unique website where the sitemap should be found.

For a better control on your different websites, you should consider using an other domain name such as `ExampleWP2.com` or even a subdomain would be enough `ExampleWP2.ExampleWP1.com`